# How do I add a label to the country name in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking to add a small label near each of the countries name that will show it's population (e.g. Brazil [200,0000] ). Is there a way to do this with Google maps JS api?

My current code for map initialization:

```
    // Define options
    var options = {
        center: {
            lat: 48.1250223,
            lng: 4.1264001
        },
        zoom: 3
    };

    // Init map
    map = new google.maps.Map( $container.get(0), options );
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can add marker to that location and add a simple text to that marker.

Comment: @vikscool, thanks. However I wanted to make it immediately visible right after the Country name so users didn't have to click on the marker / see hundreds of markers at the same time.

Comment: you can load the map with markers loaded in it and the marker object have a property called "label" where you can add your own text. For more information you can check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/
for examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the label of a marker without displaying the marker. Attached a short example. Mmmmh, or use the country flag as icon and show the label over it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker with Label</title>
    <style>
      #map {height: 100%;}
      html, body {height: 100%;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: 48.1, lng: 4.1},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

  //set the text as marker label without displayinge the marker
  var m = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 48.1, lng: 4.1},
    label: {
   color: 'purple',
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   text: 'people: 67 Mio',
     },
     icon: {
   url: 'none_marker.png',
   anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, -25),
    },
   map: map
  });
 }
    </script>
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Data for the population is not available in the Google Maps API v3.
You will need to import data from an external source.

You can check this example from Google API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/combining-data

Full code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Mashups with google.maps.Data</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
        .nicebox {
          position: absolute;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
          font-size: 13px;
          z-index: 5;
          box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -4px #333;
          padding: 5px 10px;
          background: rgb(255,255,255);
          background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(245,245,245,1) 100%);
          border: rgb(229, 229, 229) 1px solid;
        }
        #controls {
          top: 10px;
          left: 110px;
          width: 360px;
          height: 45px;
        }
        #data-box {
          top: 10px;
          left: 500px;
          height: 45px;
          line-height: 45px;
          display: none;
        }
        #census-variable {
          width: 360px;
          height: 20px;
        }
        #legend { display: flex; display: -webkit-box; padding-top: 7px }
        .color-key {
          background: linear-gradient(to right,
            hsl(5, 69%, 54%) 0%,
            hsl(29, 71%, 51%) 17%,
            hsl(54, 74%, 47%) 33%,
            hsl(78, 76%, 44%) 50%,
            hsl(102, 78%, 41%) 67%,
            hsl(127, 81%, 37%) 83%,
            hsl(151, 83%, 34%) 100%);
          flex: 1;
          -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          margin: 0 5px;
          text-align: left;
          font-size: 1.0em;
          line-height: 1.0em;
        }
        #data-value { font-size: 2.0em; font-weight: bold }
        #data-label { font-size: 2.0em; font-weight: normal; padding-right: 10px; }
        #data-label:after { content: ':' }
        #data-caret { margin-left: -5px; display: none; font-size: 14px; width: 14px}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="controls" class="nicebox">
      <div>
      <select id="census-variable">
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP02_0066PE">Percent of population over 25 that completed high
        school</option>
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP05_0017E">Median age</option>
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP05_0001E">Total population</option>
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP02_0016E">Average family size</option>
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP03_0088E">Per-capita income</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div id="legend">
        <div id="census-min">min</div>
        <div class="color-key"><span id="data-caret">&#x25c6;</span></div>
        <div id="census-max">max</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="data-box" class="nicebox">
      <label id="data-label" for="data-value"></label>
      <span id="data-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var mapStyle = [{
        'stylers': [{'visibility': 'off'}]
      }, {
        'featureType': 'landscape',
        'elementType': 'geometry',
        'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}, {'color': '#fcfcfc'}]
      }, {
        'featureType': 'water',
        'elementType': 'geometry',
        'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}, {'color': '#bfd4ff'}]
      }];
      var map;
      var censusMin = Number.MAX_VALUE, censusMax = -Number.MAX_VALUE;

      function initMap() {

        // load the map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 40, lng: -100},
          zoom: 4,
          styles: mapStyle
        });


        // set up the style rules and events for google.maps.Data
        map.data.setStyle(styleFeature);
        map.data.addListener('mouseover', mouseInToRegion);
        map.data.addListener('mouseout', mouseOutOfRegion);

        // wire up the button
        var selectBox = document.getElementById('census-variable');
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(selectBox, 'change', function() {
          clearCensusData();
          loadCensusData(selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value);
        });

        // state polygons only need to be loaded once, do them now
        loadMapShapes();

      }

      /** Loads the state boundary polygons from a GeoJSON source. */
      function loadMapShapes() {
        // load US state outline polygons from a GeoJson file
        map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/states.js', { idPropertyName: 'STATE' });

        // wait for the request to complete by listening for the first feature to be
        // added
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map.data, 'addfeature', function() {
          google.maps.event.trigger(document.getElementById('census-variable'),
              'change');
        });
      }

      /**
       * Loads the census data from a simulated API call to the US Census API.
       *
       * @param {string} variable
       */
      function loadCensusData(variable) {
        // load the requested variable from the census API (using local copies)
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', variable + '.json');
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var censusData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          censusData.shift(); // the first row contains column names
          censusData.forEach(function(row) {
            var censusVariable = parseFloat(row[0]);
            var stateId = row[1];

            // keep track of min and max values
            if (censusVariable < censusMin) {
              censusMin = censusVariable;
            }
            if (censusVariable > censusMax) {
              censusMax = censusVariable;
            }

            // update the existing row with the new data
            map.data
              .getFeatureById(stateId)
              .setProperty('census_variable', censusVariable);
          });

          // update and display the legend
          document.getElementById('census-min').textContent =
              censusMin.toLocaleString();
          document.getElementById('census-max').textContent =
              censusMax.toLocaleString();
        };
        xhr.send();
      }

      /** Removes census data from each shape on the map and resets the UI. */
      function clearCensusData() {
        censusMin = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        censusMax = -Number.MAX_VALUE;
        map.data.forEach(function(row) {
          row.setProperty('census_variable', undefined);
        });
        document.getElementById('data-box').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('data-caret').style.display = 'none';
      }

      /**
       * Applies a gradient style based on the 'census_variable' column.
       * This is the callback passed to data.setStyle() and is called for each row in
       * the data set.  Check out the docs for Data.StylingFunction.
       *
       * @param {google.maps.Data.Feature} feature
       */
      function styleFeature(feature) {
        var low = [5, 69, 54];  // color of smallest datum
        var high = [151, 83, 34];   // color of largest datum

        // delta represents where the value sits between the min and max
        var delta = (feature.getProperty('census_variable') - censusMin) /
            (censusMax - censusMin);

        var color = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          // calculate an integer color based on the delta
          color[i] = (high[i] - low[i]) * delta + low[i];
        }

        // determine whether to show this shape or not
        var showRow = true;
        if (feature.getProperty('census_variable') == null ||
            isNaN(feature.getProperty('census_variable'))) {
          showRow = false;
        }

        var outlineWeight = 0.5, zIndex = 1;
        if (feature.getProperty('state') === 'hover') {
          outlineWeight = zIndex = 2;
        }

        return {
          strokeWeight: outlineWeight,
          strokeColor: '#fff',
          zIndex: zIndex,
          fillColor: 'hsl(' + color[0] + ',' + color[1] + '%,' + color[2] + '%)',
          fillOpacity: 0.75,
          visible: showRow
        };
      }

      /**
       * Responds to the mouse-in event on a map shape (state).
       *
       * @param {?google.maps.MouseEvent} e
       */
      function mouseInToRegion(e) {
        // set the hover state so the setStyle function can change the border
        e.feature.setProperty('state', 'hover');

        var percent = (e.feature.getProperty('census_variable') - censusMin) /
            (censusMax - censusMin) * 100;

        // update the label
        document.getElementById('data-label').textContent =
            e.feature.getProperty('NAME');
        document.getElementById('data-value').textContent =
            e.feature.getProperty('census_variable').toLocaleString();
        document.getElementById('data-box').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('data-caret').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('data-caret').style.paddingLeft = percent + '%';
      }

      /**
       * Responds to the mouse-out event on a map shape (state).
       *
       * @param {?google.maps.MouseEvent} e
       */
      function mouseOutOfRegion(e) {
        // reset the hover state, returning the border to normal
        e.feature.setProperty('state', 'normal');
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the question is how to add a label next to the country name to show my custom info (e.g. population), not how to export this data. The example you provided shows what I need in a separate box at the top instead.